# Why wont React load my images from the src folder?

Tags: reactjs, image, react-image

I'm trying to get images in my react app to showcase some of the brands my family's company sells. I'm thinking of putting it in like a grid, something like this:
[image: Brands Grid] (Please excuse my aweful design, its just an idea).

So, I tried adding a picture using this way:

```
import image from '../images/brandlogos/image.png';
```

Which didn't work (i'll get to how it didn't work in a bit). So, with some research, I came across this other way, using the `require()`. And it still doesn't work.
`const klaxcar = require('../images/brandlogos/klaxcar.png');`

Now, this is what I mean by "it doesn't work":
[image: Not working]

I have no clue what this even means, I'm very new to react. It's weird because I tried to make a slideshow a couple of days ago and it worked. My only guess is, does it have to be a component? Or is there an issue with my file paths? (I put my images folder in src). Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using `create-react-app`? If not, how are you building compiling? Also, after you import the image how are you trying to use it?

Comment: Yes, I'm using create-react-app. I'm trying to use it with the <img> tag. Like this:
`<img scr={klaxcar} alt="Klaxcar" className="klaxcarlogo"/>`

Comment: Have you checked that the path is defined? e.g. if you do `import image from '../images/brandlogos/image.png';` and then under it do `console.log(image);` have you seen that there's a path there (will be the compiled version of it)

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. And it says `Module {default: "/static/media/klaxcar.23e3c7fd.png"` in the console. Also, everything compiles perfectly, which is weird since it doesnt work, but yeah. Also, I've tried changing the path of the image to something that doesn't even exist (../images/asdfasdf.png), and it gives an error as expected.

Comment: Is that what gets logged when you use import or when you use require? Those 2 aren't the same. For require you need to access the default property of the required file

Comment: Oh, that is what gets logged when using require. And this is what gets logged when using import: `/static/media/klaxcar.23e3c7fd.png`